# Unable to launch a cluster in Azure Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-workflows

Im triggering a Databricks job from Devops pipeline.It was working fine initially but after few runs the job is in pending state and failing with the below error.

```
run failed with error message
 Unexpected failure while waiting for the cluster (1031-182958-d705352n) to be ready: Cluster 1031-182958-d705352n is unusable since the cluster is unhealthy.
```

When I look at the event logs, I see the below error.

```
Message
Failed to add 1 container to the compute. Will attempt retry: true. Reason: Cloud provider launch failure

Help
A cloud provider error was encountered while launching worker nodes.
```

I checked the subscription level usage/quota, the Standard DSv2 Family vCPUs has 40% usage left.

Below is my configuration.

```
{
          "name": "'$jobName'",
          "new_cluster": {
            "spark_version": "14.0.x-scala2.12",
            "node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2",
            "num_workers": 0
            
          },
          "access_control_list": access_control_list,  
          "notebook_task": {
            "notebook_path": "'$notebookPath'",
            "base_parameters": {
              "env": "$(key)"
            }
          }
```

What could be the issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is it working now? It could be cloud provider issue that affect certain regions. You may try check Service Health to see if any outage is happening next time:

[Azure Service Health](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Health/AzureHealthBrowseBlade/%7E/serviceIssues)

Comment: Its not working.